# Importing data from an Excel workbook into SSMS

Tags: sql-server, import, ssms

I’ve been attempting to import data from an Excel workbook, mapped out like the columns within an existing table of my SQL instance. Within the SQL DB I have a primary key/identity column set-up and within the Excel workbook, I also have the primary key matching PKs in the instance.

I want to be able to import the data from the Excel workbook into the corresponding PK rows, so the data within the Excel workbook overwrites/populates into the SQL DB. (If I have a row within the Excel workbook with a PK of 1, and the next column is colour and that is 5, within the database I want the data to import so it matches up and finds the PK 1, and inserts 5 into the colour column).

Comment: do you have any examples of your create table syntax and sample data?

Comment: I'm looking for it to insert the data in columns into an existing table.

Comment: does the existing SQL table already hold any data?

Comment: @RyanGadsdon It does currently, I want to import into the existing table which holds data in already. 

I want to get it so when I import it matches up the first column in the import with the first column in the database, and inserts data into columns into the other two rows in the import (which match what's in the exisitng table).

Comment: You can use bulk insert to insert a CSV file into a database but i cant really help anymore unless you post your sample data

Comment: @RyanGadsdon If I bulk insert, am I able to insert so it will insert into existing columns and match up to existing primary keys?

Comment: Yeah it should do if you include the correct fields and you dont have duplicate primary key values